# Putting matrices side by side to create another matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have an array of 12 matrices given by following code:

```
ma = array(sample(0:127,3*4*6,replace=TRUE), c(3,4,12))
```

Let they be named A,B,C...L

I want to create a matrix which has above matrices arranged in a 4rows*3columns pattern:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

So final matrix will have 12rows and 12 columns.

I can do this following code:

```
rbind(cbind(m[,,1],m[,,2],m[,,3]),
      cbind(m[,,4],m[,,5],m[,,6]),
      cbind(m[,,7],m[,,8],m[,,9]),
      cbind(m[,,10],m[,,11],m[,,12]))
```

But I am not able to write a generic function for this:

```
matbinder(ma,n)
```

where `ma` is input matrix array and `n` is number of initial matrices to be put in one row (3 in this case).

Comment: @Jilber: Thanks for editing & making the code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use this as a sample matrix since it will have all the letters in the order you like

```
ma = array(as.vector(t(outer(letters[1:12],1:12, FUN=paste0))), c(3,4,12))
```

Then you can do the transformation like

```
a<-ma
dim(a) <- c(3,12,4)
apply(a,2,c)
```

which produces

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,] "a1" "a4" "a7" "a10" "b1" "b4" "b7" "b10" "c1" "c4"  "c7"  "c10"
 [2,] "a2" "a5" "a8" "a11" "b2" "b5" "b8" "b11" "c2" "c5"  "c8"  "c11"
 [3,] "a3" "a6" "a9" "a12" "b3" "b6" "b9" "b12" "c3" "c6"  "c9"  "c12"
 [4,] "d1" "d4" "d7" "d10" "e1" "e4" "e7" "e10" "f1" "f4"  "f7"  "f10"
 [5,] "d2" "d5" "d8" "d11" "e2" "e5" "e8" "e11" "f2" "f5"  "f8"  "f11"
 [6,] "d3" "d6" "d9" "d12" "e3" "e6" "e9" "e12" "f3" "f6"  "f9"  "f12"
 [7,] "g1" "g4" "g7" "g10" "h1" "h4" "h7" "h10" "i1" "i4"  "i7"  "i10"
 [8,] "g2" "g5" "g8" "g11" "h2" "h5" "h8" "h11" "i2" "i5"  "i8"  "i11"
 [9,] "g3" "g6" "g9" "g12" "h3" "h6" "h9" "h12" "i3" "i6"  "i9"  "i12"
[10,] "j1" "j4" "j7" "j10" "k1" "k4" "k7" "k10" "l1" "l4"  "l7"  "l10"
[11,] "j2" "j5" "j8" "j11" "k2" "k5" "k8" "k11" "l2" "l5"  "l8"  "l11"
[12,] "j3" "j6" "j9" "j12" "k3" "k6" "k9" "k12" "l3" "l6"  "l9"  "l12"
```

This works because by flipping the dimensions, we essentially build a 4 element array of 3*12 matrices which correspond to the rows we want. Then we use apply to collapse across the extra dimension.

A generic `matbinder(ma,n)` function would look like

```
matbinder <- function(ma,n) {
    d<-dim(ma)
    r<-ceiling(d[3]/n)
    a<-c(ma, rep(NA, (n*r-d[3]) * prod(d[1:2])))
    dim(a)<-c(d[1], n*d[2],r)
    apply(a,2,c)
}
```

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. Can it be modified so that if there are only 11 matrices in ma, the remaining places in final matrix are filled with 'NA'. Similarly, the function may work for command matbinder(ma,5), since currently it produces an error: dims [product 120] do not match the length of object [144].

Answer (score 0):

Using my limited knowledge, I managed following code:

```
matbinder2 = function(submat, mats_per_row){
    submat_dims = dim(submat)
    submatr = submat_dims[1]
    submatc = submat_dims[2]
    submatn = submat_dims[3]

    matc = submatc*mats_per_row
    matr = submatr* ceiling(submatn/mats_per_row)
    mat = array(NA, c(matr,matc))

    for(m in 1:submatn){
        r = 1+(floor(submatc*(m-1)/matc))*submatr
        c = 1+((submatc*(m-1))%%matc)
        i=1;j=1;k=0;l=0;
        while(TRUE){
            mat[r+l,c+k] =  submat[i,j,m]
            j=j+1; k=k+1; 
            if(j>submatc){j=1;k=0; i=i+1;l=l+1;if(i>submatr){break;}}
        }
    }
    mat
}
```