# Split a matrix in blocks of size n with offset i (vectorized method)

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I want to split matrices of size `k x l` into blocks of size `n x n` considering an ofset `o` (Like Mathematica's [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html#29979) function does).

For example, given a matrix `A` like

```
A <- matrix(seq(1:16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

and block size = 3, offset = 1, I want as output the four submatrices that I'd get from

```
A[1:3, 1:3]
A[1:3, 2:4]
A[2:4, 1:3]
A[2:4, 2:4]
```

If offset were equal to 2 or 3, the output for this example should be only the submatrix that I get from

```
A[1:3, 1:3]
```

How can I vectorize this?

Comment: You could index negatively, though this may be case-specific: `apply(combn(c(-1, -1, -4, -4), 2), 2, function(x){list(A[x[1], x[2]])})`

Comment: What should we have if `offset == 2`?

Comment: @Psidom, an offset of 2 rows and 2 columns. In the 4 x 4 matrix of the example above offsets 2 and 3 both give the submatrix `A[1:3, 1:3]`

Comment: This might be similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299171/function-to-split-a-matrix-into-sub-matrices-in-r/24300097 - particularly if the simplification-to-array parts are removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way. Here is how I'd do it by writing a `myPartition` function which simulates the mathematica `Partition` function. Firstly use `Map` to construct possible index along the row and column axis where we use `seq` to take `offset` into consideration, and then use `cross2` from `purrr` to construct a list of all possible combinations of the subset index. Finally use `lapply` to subset the matrix and return a list of subset matrix;

The testing results on offset `1`, `2` and `3` are as follows which seems to behave as expected:

```
library(purrr)
ind <- function(k, n, o) Map(`:`, seq(1, k-n+1, by = o), seq(n, k, by = o))

# this is a little helper function that generates subset index according to dimension of the 
# matrix, the first sequence construct the starting point of the subset index with an interval 
# of o which is the offset while the second sequence construct the ending point of the subset index
# use Map to construct vector from start to end which in OP's case will be 1:3 and 2:4. 

myPartition <- function(mat, n, o) {
    lapply(cross2(ind(nrow(mat),n,o), ind(ncol(mat),n,o)), function(i) mat[i[[1]], i[[2]]])
}

# This is basically an lapply. we use cross2 to construct combinations of all subset index
# which will be 1:3 and 1:3, 1:3 and 2:4, 2:4 and 1:3 and 2:4 and 2:4 in OP's case. Use lapply
# to loop through the index and subset.

# Testing case for offset = 1
myPartition(A, 3, 1)

# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    9
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    7   11

# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    6   10
# [2,]    3    7   11
# [3,]    4    8   12

# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    9   13
# [2,]    6   10   14
# [3,]    7   11   15

# [[4]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    6   10   14
# [2,]    7   11   15
# [3,]    8   12   16

# Testing case for offset = 2
myPartition(A, 3, 2)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    9
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    7   11

# Testing case for offset = 3
myPartition(A, 3, 3)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    9
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    7   11
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this using `base` R, the idea is to generate all possible windows (i.e. `winds`) of size `n*n` while taking into account the `offset`. Then print all possible permutations of `winds`'s elements in matrix `A` (i.e. `perms`). It works for any `A` of size `k*l`.

```
A <- matrix(seq(1:16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
c <- ncol(A); r <- nrow(A)
offset <- 1; size <- 3
sq <- seq(1, max(r,c), offset)
winds <- t(sapply(sq, function(x) c(x,(x+size-1))))
winds <- winds[winds[,2]<=max(r, c),] # check the range
if (is.vector(winds)) dim(winds) <- c(1,2) # vector to matrix
perms <- expand.grid(list(1:nrow(winds), 1:nrow(winds)))
out=apply(perms, 1, function(x) {
   a11 <- winds[x[1],1];a12 <- winds[x[1],2];a21 <- winds[x[2],1];a22 <- winds[x[2],2]
   if (ifelse(r<c, a12<=r, a22<=c)) { # check the range
       cat("A[", a11, ":", a12, ", ", a21, ":", a22, "]", sep="", "\n")
       print(A[a11:a12, a21:a22])
   }
})

# A[1:3, 1:3]
     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    9
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    7   11
# A[2:4, 1:3]
     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    6   10
# [2,]    3    7   11
# [3,]    4    8   12
# A[1:3, 2:4]
     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    9   13
# [2,]    6   10   14
# [3,]    7   11   15
# A[2:4, 2:4]
     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    6   10   14
# [2,]    7   11   15
# [3,]    8   12   16
```

For `size=3` and `offset=2` or  `offset=3`:

```
# A[1:3, 1:3]
     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    9
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    7   11
```

For `offset=2` and  `size=2`:

```
# A[1:2, 1:2]
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    5
# [2,]    2    6
# A[3:4, 1:2]
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    7
# [2,]    4    8
# A[1:2, 3:4]
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    9   13
# [2,]   10   14
# A[3:4, 3:4]
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   11   15
# [2,]   12   16
```