# Loop to through matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix of 256*256 ,I need to break this matrix to get 1024 blocks (256*256/(8*8)). Then I need calculate mean,standard deviation,Kurtosis,standard deviation of each block (1024 blocks)

The dataset which I want from from matrix is

S.no Mean standard deviation Kurtosis Skewness 
1
2
.
.
.
.
1024

I am stuck in looping and retrieving the values to compute the statistics.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge. Where are you stuck exactly? Can you show us your code? Also please read - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Function to split a matrix into sub-matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299171/function-to-split-a-matrix-into-sub-matrices-in-r/24299527#24299527)

Comment: Yes sure...   I have converted an Image to a matrix of 256*256.First I am trying to calculate mean,I am getting error,Below is the code.                                                                                          
  y <- resize(image, w = 256, h = 256)
View(y)

result=data.frame((y))

colnames(result) <- c("i","Mean")
for (i in 1:nrow(result)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(result)) {
    squared <- mean(result[i:8, j:8])
  result[i, 2] <- squared
  }
}

Comment: matsplitter<-function(M, r, c) {
  rg <- (row(M)-1)%/%r+1
  cg <- (col(M)-1)%/%c+1
  rci <- (rg-1)*max(cg) + cg
  N <- prod(dim(M))/r/c
  cv <- unlist(lapply(1:N, function(x) M[rci==x]))
  dim(cv)<-c(r,c,N)
  cv
  }

asa <-matsplitter(y,8,8) 

This code works to split the matrix in 1024 smaller block ,but I am not able to calculte the mean,standard deviation,skewness,kurtosis,as I am 
not able to read the output.

Comment: @PraveenChougale Try `apply(X = asa, MARGIN = 3, FUN = mean)`. It should return a vector of length 1024.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot got it.But I need summary of each block,by using FUN=mean ,I am getting only mean

Comment: @PraveenChougale Please put the additional information from your comments in your question, i.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50579071/edit

Answer (score 1):

`m` is your matrix.  `yourMatrixFunction` is a function you need to define that works on a single `8x8`-matrix and acquires what you want.

```
m <- matrix(1,nrow=256,ncol=256)

first <- seq(1,256,by=8)
last  <- rep(8,length(first)) %>% cumsum

pair  <- Map(function(...)cbind(...),first,last) %>% expand.grid(.,.)
first <- pair[[1]]
last  <- pair[[2]]

all_m <- Map(function(x,y) m[x[1]:x[2],y[1]:y[2]],x=first,y=last)

lapply(all_m,yourMatrixFunction)
```